# Размер массива как float выражение

Tags: c, constexpr

У меня есть такой код:

```
typedef float point[3];
typedef point arr[M_PI/0.001][M_PI/0.001];
```

Как надо преобразовать выражение в скобках, чтобы код компилировался?

Comment: А что вы хотите? Например, если у вас получится 31415.926 элементов массива - то это 31416 или 31415 элементов? А 314159.26? (Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что число элементов в массиве - всегда целое.) Понимает, чтобы код **компилировался** и чтобы он **правильно работал** - это все же несколько разные вещи, правда?

Comment: Мне не нужна точность до единицы, я просто делаю аппроксимацию одной формулы. И я уже нашел способ: добавил (int) перед выражениями.

Comment: Ваше решение - 31415. Если это не то, что требуется - вы получите неприятности. Еще раз - "компилируется" - совсем не значит "правильно работает". *"Мне не нужна точность до единицы"*... Странно это слышать, откровенно говоря.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема состоит в недостаточном понимании того факта, что массив вполне материален. Это физически существующие ячейки памяти, количество которых может выражаться только натуральным числом (включая ноль).

Затолкав в программу (int) вы насильно заставили машину округлить ваши доли Пи до ближайшего целого вниз, что разумеется, повлияет на логику работы программы и создаст как риск вылета за границу массива, так и пропуска одной ячейки - как карта ляжет.

Очевидно, что ваша программа должна работать в долях пи, так что массив нужно заводить на тысячу ячеек, а индексировать его обязательно **целым** числом.

В противном случае, вы напишите уродливую, медленную (на каждом обращении округлять - да на вас Грета-как-ее-там наорет за лишний обогрев атмосферы процессором!) и не всегда верно работающую программу.